# Fade Slideshow Jquery Issue

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow

i have created a slideshow, using jquery which has fade effect, the problem with the slideshow is if i add image, it shows properly, but if i add text instead of image, the text bounce bottom to top, i want it to be fixed on top. Actually the issue is likely because, what i am doing is, i have six `li` i am enabling first `li` and disabling rest, now i am giving the fadeout effect to first `li` and fadein effect to next `li`, now by the time the first `li` fades out and next `li` fades in, at that time, the text bounces, but i dont understand why this does not happens with image, here is my complete code.

You can [download full project](http://gp.stage.asentechdev1.com/slider.rar) and view

Currently the div contains image, if you replace that with h1 element you can see the erroneous output

Comment: Use the jQuery.cycle plugin.  It'll make slideshows **much** easier for you rather than re-inventing the wheel. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: can you give me any example, using jQuery.cycle, actually i want to make a slideshow which will contain image and text, and should have fade effect, does this plugin have that capability, can you show me some demo's available, how can i implement this plugin in right way

Comment: See answer for a simple jquery.cycle solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using jquery.cycle, setting a fade effect is as simple as below.  You HTML should look something like:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="slide">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <img ... />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <img ... />
    </div>
    <!-- more slides ... -->
</div>
```

Then your javascript is:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:'fade',
    slideExpr: '.slide'
});
```

The fade effect (fx) is a standard one within the cycle plugin.  `slideExpr` defines a jquery selector to select the slide elements within the main (in this case `#slideshow`) wrapper for your slides.